# Laravel 5 Dynamic Named Routes

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I want to use `route()` to generate the urls.

e.g.

`route('auth.facebook.getSocialAuth')`

`route('auth.twitter.getSocialAuth')`

in `routes.php` is there a way to dynamically generate the 'as' part of the route?

if CodeIgniter, what i would do is put $1 to get the dynamic {provider}

```
Route::get('connect/{provider}', ['as' => 'auth.$1.getSocialAuth', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getSocialAuth']);
```

How can i achieve that in Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add parameter to your route like this:

routes.php with parameter:

```
Route::get('connect/{provider}', ['as' => 'getSocialAuth', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getSocialAuth']);
```

route method with paramter:

```
route('getSocialAuth', [$provider]);
```

action method with parameter:

```
action('Auth\AuthController@getSocialAuth', [$provider]);
```